# Name of this Plant and Care recommendations

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-care

I bought this Plant three days ago from Plant Nursery, but unfortunately they didnt mention the name of this plant. So i brought it home and cleaned the pot and just places under growing light.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a ***Philodendron Xanadu*** also known as  ***Philodendron bipinnatifidum***.

Based on that its care should be similar to other *Philodendrons* so:

- No direct light but would benefit from bright indirect light and possibly would tolerate lower light conditions as well.
- Water when soil is dry. Under watering is less risky than over watering.

[Philodendron Xanadu Care & Info Guide](https://hortology.co.uk/products/philodendron-winterbourn-xanadu-philodendron#:%7E:text=Philodendron%20Xanadu%20Care%20%26%20Info%20Guide,having%20its%20roots%20too%20wet.)

**Update**:

This is now called ***Thaumatophyllum bipinnatifidum*** as it has been reclassified, but the care is all the same. [So why is Philodendron bipinnatifidum no longer considered a Philodendron?](https://www.house-plant-hobbyist.com/blog/2019/5/20/thaumatophyllum)